# Getting exception in reading mails from Gmail IMAP server using Lumisoft

Tags: asp.net, imap, gmail-imap, lumisoft

I have developed web application which is reading mails from Gmail IMAP server and I have used Lumisoft.Net for this.

With my account everything is working just fine but with my client's account it's throwing this error:

```
System.Exception: Read length can't be bigger than source string !
   at LumiSoft.Net.IMAP.Client.IMAP_Client.Fetch(Boolean uid, IMAP_t_SeqSet seqSet, IMAP_t_Fetch_i[] items, EventHandler`1 callback)
   at GetOutput.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

I am getting this exception from the following code

```
if (folder.FolderName.Contains("All Mail"))
{    
imap.SelectFolder(folder.FolderName);
    imap.Fetch(
                                    false,
                                    IMAP_t_SeqSet.Parse("1:*"),
                                    new IMAP_t_Fetch_i[]{
                                    new IMAP_t_Fetch_i_Envelope(),
                                    new IMAP_t_Fetch_i_Flags(),
                                    new IMAP_t_Fetch_i_InternalDate(),
                                    new IMAP_t_Fetch_i_Rfc822Size(),
                                    new IMAP_t_Fetch_i_Uid()
                                },
                                    this.m_pImap_Fetch_MessageItems_UntaggedResponseInbox
                                );
}
```

I am big trouble due to this so please anyone can help me then it will be really great. Please help me.

Thanks,
Anvesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
m_pImap.SelectFolder(folder);
//m_pImap.Search(false, "UTF-8", "UNSEEN");

// Start fetching.
m_pImap.Fetch(
    false,
    IMAP_t_SeqSet.Parse("1:*"),
    new IMAP_t_Fetch_i[]{
        //new IMAP_Search_Key_Unseen(),
        new IMAP_t_Fetch_i_Envelope(),
        new IMAP_t_Fetch_i_Flags(),
        new IMAP_t_Fetch_i_InternalDate(),
        new IMAP_t_Fetch_i_Rfc822Size(),
        new IMAP_t_Fetch_i_Uid()
    },

    this.m_pImap_Fetch_MessageItems_UntaggedResponse
);
```